# ExpectedConditions is throwing error in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I want to implement ExpectedConditions in my framework but it is throwing some error which i'm not able to understand. can someone help me in this.

### Step Definition

```
this.Then(/^Select Any Opty and click on New button$/, async () => {
    cmBrowser.sleep(10000);
    await cmBrowser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(await loginPO.optyList()),20000);
    var list=await loginPO.optyList();
});
```

### page object

```
this.optyList = function () {
    // return $$("table[role='grid'] th span a");
    return element.all(by.xpath("//a/ancestor::th[@scope='row']"));
}
```

### Error Log

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at ProtractorExpectedConditions.presenceOf (C:\Users\srongala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\expectedConditions.js:341:40)
    at ProtractorExpectedConditions.visibilityOf (C:\Users\srongala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\expectedConditions.js:381:30)
    at World.(anonymous) (C:\Users\srongala\Documents\My Received Files\Automation\Proc\Test_modules\step_definitions\PGS_ES.js:47:39)
    at runMicrotasks ((anonymous))
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

The application i'm using is non angular applicatio.. i reviewed solutions provided in the others questions and they said like need to use `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true` but i tried both `browser.waitForAngularEnabled();` and `browser.ignoreSynchronization=true`, both are not working.

Comment: your code may cause lots of bugs. As I have mentioned in one of your previous question, all browser methods return promises and require `await` to stop execution before the promise is resolved. Your `.sleep()` function doesn't do anything in this context. As oppose to that, the first argument `.wait()` takes is function that returns promise, and don't require `await`. Because of such little things your code produces unpredictable results

Comment: Go over this page https://www.protractortest.org/#/api and take a look at how each method works, otherwise it'll get worse, because you're building very complex framework. And eventually you'll hit the ceiling and won't be able to expand it, because you'll be maintaining it all your time

Comment: @Sergey, what you mean by "all browser methods return promises and require await to stop execution before the promise is resolved. " .. can you please just add some answer like thing and show me.. i'm not that much familiar with protractor cucumber.. it will be very helpful to me seriously.

Comment: are you talking about my page objects that are returning elements?

Comment: A JavaScript method is a property of an object containing a function definition. So because `browser` is an object. Everything that you call against it and has parenthesis is method (function of the object). Thus `browser.wait()`, `browser.sleep()`, `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` etc are methods of `browser`. So all of them and not only return Promise. Before `async/await` you should've handled them with `.then` syntax. Otherwise, JS schedules your promises and goes to the next line without waiting for its resolution

Comment: what it means for you basically is that your `sleep` doesn't do what it supposed to. Now in 2019, we have `async/await` and no need to build these 100 level of `.then()` blocks. Instead you need to use `await` which will make JS to stop, until the promise is resolved. long story short use `await` before functions that return promises. Exception is first agrument of `browser.wait()` because it take function only and deals with it under the hood

Comment: @Sergy, what ever you said is correct... But in my case i need to use sleep also because page loading time taking too long.. So i need to use some sleep time and then wait time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203196/discussion-between-sergey-pleshakov-and-satish-rongala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the locator definition from function to a variable?
Also you don't have to use await twice in the expected conditions line.
Try the following:

**Page Object**

```
// You should specify the index if using .all (with .get(index); at the end)
this.optyList = element.all(by.xpath("//a/ancestor::th[@scope='row']"));
```

**Spec** (Here you could try with `visibilityOf` or `presenceOf`)

```
this.Then(/^Select Any Opty and click on New button$/,async ()=>{
    await cmBrowser.wait(EC.presenceOf(loginPO.optyList),20000);
    // or:
    await cmBrowser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(loginPO.optyList),20000);
});
```

Comment: Hi Joaquin, actually in my test application there is some page loading issues is there so when i used this expected condition i'm getting this error and also `browser.sleep` also not pausing the execution

Comment: i will definitely look in to the suggestions you stated and will let you know.. but please available if your solution won't work..

Comment: also don't forget that `browser.sleep()` also needs await in front of it

Comment: Sure Joaquin.. will definitely do that

Answer (score 0):

`visibilityOf()` accept `ElementFinder`, not `ElmentFinderArray`, you should not pass into an element array.

```
this.Then(/^Select Any Opty and click on New button$/, async () => {
    cmBrowser.sleep(10000);
    await cmBrowser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(await loginPO.optyList().first()),20000);
    var list=await loginPO.optyList();
});
```